# add custom property to custom class and initialize class

Tags: swift, class

I am trying to initialize a custom class that inherits from SKSpriteNode. Currently the class definition looks like this

```
import SpriteKit

class PassengerNode: SKSpriteNode {
let passengerStart: Int = 2
let passengerDestination: Int = 0

init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "passenger1")        
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    self.zPosition = 100
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func updateTexture(newTexture: SKTexture) {
    self.texture = newTexture
}
```

}

I want to have passengerStart and passsengerDestination assigned to the Object, respectively to the instance of the class. And ideally these both values can be different with every instantiation.

When I instantiate the Class Object I think of something like

```
let newObject = PassengerNode(start: 1, destination: 0, texture: "passenger1")
```

But I dont get it working... How do I need to change my init?
Does someone have a helping thought?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write an init method for your subclass which takes those
three parameters:

```
class PassengerNode: SKSpriteNode {
    let passengerStart: Int
    let passengerDestination: Int

    init(start: Int, destination: Int, texture: String) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: texture)  
        passengerStart = start
        passengerDestination = destination
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: texture.size())
        self.zPosition = 100
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // ... more methods ...
}
```

The init method must initialize the properties of the subclass and
then call `super.init`.